# Splitting a 5V digital signal in two, for two different ICs

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, resistors, sensor, split

I have an application where a hall-effect switch's digital 5V signal needs to be read by two separate ICs, a motor driver and a microcontroller. Can I simply route the signal to both inputs, or do I need to effectively 'split' the signal and repeat it to both inputs? If so, is there a simple circuit to accomplish this?

Both the microcontroller and motor driver have a built in resistive pull-down.

Probably a very simple answer, but I want to clear my thinking on it.

Comment: Usually the ability of a logic output to drive multiple inputs is referred to as “fan out”

Comment: generally yes, and a fan-out of 2 (as @Bryan alludes to) is not a big deal. However, you have provided no specs, so what you could do on your own is check the required voltage levels at both inputs against the switch's output, and also the drive current into both loads (parallel R).

Answer (score 1):

Almost surely, assuming the Hall switch has a push-pull output, but the answer depends on whether the Hall switch can drive both inputs in parallel (the pulldown resistance). Usually those pulldown resistances represent a very light load and are only there to assure a low level is read when the input is disconnected.

**Some** Hall switches are open-collector and require a pull-up resistor, at which point it gets a bit dicier because the pull-up has to be high enough that the Hall switch can drive it, and low enough that a "high" registers as such with both the MCU and the motor driver.